# updated image stores in database but not folder in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

problem is that company_photo stores in database but not store in company_photos folder, please tell me where i going wrong..

```php
public function update(Request $request, Company $company,CompanyOtherInfo $CompanyOtherInfo ) 

    {
        //dd($company);
        //dd(request()->all());

       if($request->hasFile('company_photo')){

            $files=public_path().'/company_photos/'.$req->input('company_photo1');
            File::delete($files);
            //dd($files);
            $file = $req->file('company_photo');

            $destinationPath = public_path().'/company_photos/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);



           // echo  $filename;
        }
        else{
            $filename=$request->input('company_photo1');
        }
//dd($request);
//dd($filename);

      $company::where('companies.company_id',$company->company_id)
                       ->update([

            'company_photo' => $filename,            
            'company_name' => request('company_name'),
            'company_email' => request('company_email'),
            'company_mobile' => request('company_mobile'),
            'company_country' => request('company_country'),
            'company_state' => request('company_state'),
            'company_city' => request('company_city'),
            'company_pincode' => request('company_pincode'),
            'company_address' => request('company_address'),
            'industry_id' => request('industry_id'),
            'segment_id' => request('segment_id'),
            'company_code' => request('company_code'),
            'contact_person'=>request('contact_person'),


        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you had is you changed the variable `$request` to `$req` half way through your code:

Change these lines:

```
$files = public_path().'/company_photos/'.$req->input('company_photo1');
$file = $req->file('company_photo');
```

to:

```
$files = public_path().'/company_photos/'.$request->input('company_photo1');
$file = $request->file('company_photo');
```

Here is the code with a little refactor:

```
$filename = $request->input('company_photo1');

if ($request->hasFile('company_photo')) {

    $files = public_path().'/company_photos/'.$fileName;

    File::delete($files);

    $file = $request->file('company_photo');

    $file->move(public_path().'/company_photos/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```